# Comparig documents in couchdb and taking count

Tags: javascript, couchdb

The documents in my database are as below:

```
_id             999A
properties      {cust_id:1234,
                 loc_id:ABC}

_id             999B
properties      {cust_id:1234,
                 loc_id:ABD}

_id             999C
properties      {cust_id:1235,
                 loc_id:ABD}

_id             999D
properties      {cust_id:1235,
                 loc_id:ABE}
```

I need to get the count and id of customers who visit two specific clinics (such as ABC and ABD). What should my query look like?

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a view 'by_location'

   ```
   //map function content
   function(doc) {
       emit(doc.properties.loc_id, doc.properties.cust_id);
   }
   //reduce function
   _count
   ```
2. now query without reduce to get each customer visit: `http://localhost:5984/clinic/_design/visits/_view/by_location?key="ABC"&reduce=false`
3. and query with reduce to get the count: `http://localhost:5984/clinic/_design/visits/_view/by_location?key="ABC"`